# Convert time in HH:MM:SS format to seconds only?

Tags: php, time

How to turn time in format `HH:MM:SS` into a flat seconds number?

**P.S.** Time could be sometimes in format `MM:SS` only.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

No need to `explode` anything:

```
$str_time = "23:12:95";

$str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $str_time);

sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
```

And if you don't want to use regular expressions:

```
$str_time = "2:50";

sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$time_seconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;
```

Comment: When using time functions I had to mess around with timezones to get it right, but this is much simpler.

Comment: Mistake in the last line:`$time_seconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;`

Should be `$time_seconds = isset($hours) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $minutes * 60 + $seconds;`

Comment: Actually, shouldn't the last line be: 
isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes; 
If there is no hour, then need to treat hours as minutes and minutes as seconds. 
For example: 10:01 should be 601 seconds.

Comment: @rlorenzo: Yes. Someone edited my answer and broke it.

Comment: Colons do not need to be escaped in the pattern.  `[\d]` is more simply expressed as `\d`.

Answer (score 117):

I think the **easiest method** would be to use `strtotime()` function:

```php
$time = '21:30:10';
$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
echo $seconds;

// same with objects (for php5.3+)
$time = '21:30:10';
$dt = new DateTime("1970-01-01 $time", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$seconds = (int)$dt->getTimestamp();
echo $seconds;
```

[demo](https://eval.in/84739)

---

Function [`date_parse()`](http://php.net/date-parse) can also be used for parsing date and time:

```php
$time = '21:30:10';
$parsed = date_parse($time);
$seconds = $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];
```

[demo](https://eval.in/84731)

---

If you will parse format `MM:SS` with `strtotime()` or `date_parse()` it will fail (`date_parse()` is used in `strtotime()` and `DateTime`), because when you input format like `xx:yy` parser assumes it is `HH:MM` and not `MM:SS`. I would suggest checking format, and prepend `00:` if you only have `MM:SS`.

[demo `strtotime()`](https://eval.in/84740)
[demo `date_parse()`](https://eval.in/84730)

---

If you have hours more than 24, then you can use next function (it will work for `MM:SS` and `HH:MM:SS` format):

```php
function TimeToSec($time) {
    $sec = 0;
    foreach (array_reverse(explode(':', $time)) as $k => $v) $sec += pow(60, $k) * $v;
    return $sec;
}
```

[demo](https://eval.in/418460)

Comment: `strtotime()` does not allow the hours go beyond 24 - using 25 or higher will return "false".

Comment: Your 3rd answer for times over 24 hours is exactly what I needed. The `array_reverse` and explode on `:` then causing one more trip through the `foreach` and another `pow` (so that both *hh:mm* AND *hh:mm:ss* work without modification of the function) is a stroke of genius. Code par excellence. I can hardly imagine a more efficient example. Thanks!

Comment: @Glavić Some how helps me too

Comment: What if it is containing dot `.` like this `00:20:55.60000`? I tried to post a question, but there seems a problem.

Comment: @KeepMove: remove microseconds, on round them to seconds part.

Comment: I just looked at the first answer, and thought, what if I used the Unix epoch... up vote from me!

Comment: The third option works for every valid format I could throw at it. 

Comment: @Ari The third option works with milliseconds and nanoseconds, too, as it's just a comma-value. It's a really interesting way to solve this...

Comment: The first option `$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");` should be the shortest answer and the accepted one. The use of `1970-01-01` is genial!

Answer (score 17):

```
    $time = 00:06:00;
    $timeInSeconds = strtotime($time) - strtotime('TODAY');
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `strtotime` function to return the number of seconds from `today 00:00:00`.

```
$seconds= strtotime($time) - strtotime('00:00:00');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 6):

In pseudocode:

```
split it by colon
seconds = 3600 * HH + 60 * MM + SS
```

Comment: As he wrote, it's pseudocode. "Pretend code" to explain how something could be done.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's pseudocode or not because the question requires supporting MM:SS format which this answer does not.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```php
$time = "21:30:10";
$timeArr = array_reverse(explode(":", $time));
$seconds = 0;
foreach ($timeArr as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key > 2) break;
    $seconds += pow(60, $key) * $value;
}
echo $seconds;
```

Comment: I love it! $time = "01:23:54:21:30:10" gives me an answer of 1087421410 seconds.

Comment: Try it now. Ofcourse you can pass something like "898989:8989898:899899", but I assume basic validations will be done on the time entered before code reached to the seconds calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
function timeToSeconds($time)
{
     $timeExploded = explode(':', $time);
     if (isset($timeExploded[2])) {
         return $timeExploded[0] * 3600 + $timeExploded[1] * 60 + $timeExploded[2];
     }
     return $timeExploded[0] * 3600 + $timeExploded[1] * 60;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function time2sec($time) {
    $durations = array_reverse(explode(':', $item->duration));
    $second = array_shift($durations);
    foreach ($durations as $duration) {
        $second += (60 * $duration);
    }
    return $second;
}
echo time2sec('4:52'); // 292
echo time2sec('2:01:42'); // 7302
```

Comment: This answer is cleanest, except for `$item->duration`, which should just be replaced by `$time`.  And it should probably do some casting.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 32 bit PHP version: 7.2.31 i get some error on all versions posted here.
If the time was 00:00:00 or 00:00:00 the zeros 00 were returned and used as "" empty string, and calculation with empty string returns error "A Non WELLNUMERIC blabla.

This Works also with more then 24hours:

```
function TimeToSec(string $time) {
   $timearray = explode(":",$time);
   $hours   = (int)$timearray[0];
   $minutes = (int)$timearray[1];
   $seconds = (int)$timearray[2];;

  //echo "Hours: " . $hours ."<br>";
   //echo "minutes: " . $minutes ."<br>";
   //echo "seconds: " . $seconds ."<br>";

   $value = ($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds;
return $value;
}

echo TimeToSec("25:00:30");
```

Answer (score 0):

To cover HH:MM:SS, MM:SS, and SS cases.

```
function getSeconds(string $time) {
    $match = sscanf($time, "%d:%d:%d", $t1, $t2, $t3);
    return match ($match) {
        1 => $t1,
        2 => $t1 * 60 + $t2,
        3 => $t1 * 3600 + $t2 * 60 + $t3,
        default => 0
    };
}

echo getSeconds("02:50");   // 170
echo getSeconds("1:02:50"); // 3770
echo getSeconds("50");      // 50
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Will work with any format ("HH:MM:SS", "MM:SS" or "SS")

```
function timeToSeconds(string $time): int { 
    return array_reduce(explode(':', $time), fn ($x, $i) => $x * 60 + $i, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$time    = '21:32:32';
$seconds = 0;
$parts   = explode(':', $time);

if (count($parts) > 2) {
    $seconds += $parts[0] * 3600;
}
$seconds += $parts[1] * 60;
$seconds += $parts[2];
```

Comment: What if it was only 32:32 without the hour?

Comment: Then it wouldn't work. You obviously need to validate the format first. And remove the first $seconds += part

Comment: How would flipping the array help?

Comment: No.. If HH is not present flipping the array will result in the seconds getting treated as hours.