# Convert HH:MM:SS string to seconds only in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I am having similar requirement as this: [Convert time in HH:MM:SS format to seconds only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-hhmmss-to-seconds-only)

but in javascript. I have seen many examples of converting seconds into different formats but not HH:MM:SS into seconds.

Comment: oops.. sorry for the typo. yes, it's time hh:mm:ss

Comment: What is the `DD` in `HH:MM:DD`?

Comment: It's the same algorithm as is in that PHP question.

Comment: Well.. H(Hour) == 3600 seconds, M(minute) == 60 seconds... so..

Comment: Only solution I think of is to split the string in array and then multiply 3600 to hour and multiply 60 to min and add all with seconds part. Is this is the simplest solution?

Comment: @kuul13 yeah, that's the simplest solution :)

Comment: Thank you guys! I thought there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var hms = '02:04:33';   // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 

console.log(seconds);
```

Comment: Here's a prototype version of this!
`String.prototype.toSeconds = function () {
 if (!this) return null;
 var hms = this.split(':');
 return (+hms[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+hms[1]) * 60 + (+hms[2] || 0); 
}`


NOTE: the `|| 0` at the end is good for any implementation of this code - it prevents issues with a (still valid) time representation of HH:MM (Chrome type="time" inputs will output in this format when seconds=0).

Comment: The use of "+" operator to convert numeric string to number is not a good idea. It's short and looks "clever", but it's confusing and not clean code. Use parseInt(x, 10) instead. And avoid one-liner. Also prevent errors by undefined input. For example: it's not a string, has no ":" or only "HH:MM". etc.

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan of the legibility of shenanigans with `+` either, personally, but it actually seems to reject a lot more highly questionable input as `NaN` than `parseInt()` does.  `parseInt(s, 10)` accepts roughly  `^\s*([+-]?\d+).*$`, which wouldn't be so bad if it weren't for the fact it basically silently munches up any junk after the last `\d`... Bit of a menace by itself, with the name it has and everything, if you ask me. Any function that claims to 'parse ints' but thinks '6ix9ine' is a number not a rapper, and that '1 000 000' == 1  & '26,507' = 26 is getting side-eye.'

Answer (score 97):

This function handels "HH:MM:SS" as well as "MM:SS" or "SS".

```
function hmsToSecondsOnly(str) {
    var p = str.split(':'),
        s = 0, m = 1;

    while (p.length > 0) {
        s += m * parseInt(p.pop(), 10);
        m *= 60;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 66):

This can be done quite resiliently with the following:

```
'01:02:03'.split(':').reduce((acc,time) => (60 * acc) + +time);
```

This is because each unit of time within the hours, minutes and seconds is a multiple of 60 greater than the smaller unit.  Time is split into hour minutes and seconds components, then reduced to seconds by using the accumulated value of the higher units multiplied by 60 as it goes through each unit.

The  `+time` is used to cast the time to a number.

It basically ends up doing: `(60 * ((60 * HHHH) + MM)) + SS`

If only seconds is passed then the result would be a string, so to fix that we could cast the entire result to an int:

```
+('03'.split(':').reduce((acc,time) => (60 * acc) + +time));
```

Comment: thats actually pretty damn clever.. question is how fast this is compared to a calculation

Comment: Yes it's clever, but a good example of creating difficult to maintain code for no practical gain. It saves 4 characters when minified vs a minified version of the accepted answer. Given that many web pages are now in excess of 1MB, that saving is somewhat less than insignificant.

Comment: Although this answer isn't as comprehensible, it does gracefully handle both `HH:MM:SS` as well as `MM:SS`, while the accepted answer does not.

Comment: This one has a type conversion bug, if there only the seconds portion is given.
You need to explicit inititlise the memo with 0 to prevent it.
Works:
`'03'.split(':').reduce((acc,time) => (60 * acc) + +time, 0);`
Fails because returns an unexpected string:
`'03'.split(':').reduce((acc,time) => (60 * acc) + +time);`

Comment: @FelixGertz Well spotted, I'll edit in a fix for that case.

Comment: With @FelixGertz fix, this answer also handles milliseconds. `e.g. (1) '1:1:6.890' => 3666.89 (2) '.890' => 0.89`.

Comment: This answer also handles 60 hour days, and 60 day months. `MM:DD:HH:MM:SS`

Comment: @squarecandy Yes, interesting point.  I believe the `:` as a separator is a good way to indicate that it is a unit of 60 (as in minutes and seconds). Once you get to days and months you are probably wanting to compare Date objects as you are no longer dealing with an elapsed time that has already been calculated.

Comment: I like this answer because I can tell right away that the code is correct.

Comment: @Paul My time input is in '2 h 10 m' format. How can I convert this into seconds?

Comment: @KhadijaDaruwala You can split the string by your separator `(space)` `'2 h 10 m'.split(' ')` to make it an array, access the correct offsets, multiply by the units (seonds in an hour, seconds in a minute), and add.

Answer (score 17):

Since the [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) function of the Date object gets the milliseconds since 1970/01/01, we can do this:

```
var time = '12:23:00';
var seconds = new Date('1970-01-01T' + time + 'Z').getTime() / 1000;
```

Comment: Just realized, this doesnt work with daylight savings time. Need to use the actual date

Comment: @Yablargo Thanks. Previous version didn't work very well with local timezone, so i edited it to use iso 8601 utc datetime format.

Answer (score 15):

Convert `hh:mm:ss` string to seconds in one line. Also allowed `h:m:s` format and `mm:ss`, `m:s` etc

```
'08:45:20'.split(':').reverse().reduce((prev, curr, i) => prev + curr*Math.pow(60, i), 0)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Convert `hh:mm:ss` string to seconds in one line. Also allowed `h:m:s` format and `mm:ss`, `m:s` etc.

Comment: Nice answer! But you could skip the `reverse()`: '00:01:11'.split(':').reduce((val, entry, i) => val + entry * (3600/Math.pow(60, i)), 0) === 71

Comment: @CMR, interesting aproach, but in case of `mm:ss` it will not work correctly.

Comment: Math.pow is very slow and can be avoided as shown in other answers based on reduce

Comment: If you are going to call this more than a couple of times, you can use a lookup table to avoid Math.pow. For example `const powersOf60LUT = [1, 60, 3600];` would be enough for hh:mm:ss. You just have to replace the Math.pow block with `powersOf60LUT[i]`

Comment: @PaulHide My time input is in '2 h 10 m' format. How can I convert this into seconds?

Answer (score 14):

This is the most clear, easy to understand solution:

```js
function convertDurationtoSeconds(duration){
    const [hours, minutes, seconds] = duration.split(':');
    return Number(hours) * 60 * 60 + Number(minutes) * 60 + Number(seconds);
};

const input = '01:30:45';
const output = convertDurationtoSeconds(input);
console.log(`${input} is ${output} in seconds`);
```

Comment: My time input is in '2 h 10 m' format. How can I convert this into seconds?

Comment: you need to default seconds to 0, for when they are omitted like in 'HH:MM'

Answer (score 11):

try

```
time="12:12:12";
tt=time.split(":");
sec=tt[0]*3600+tt[1]*60+tt[2]*1;
```

Comment: ah, that *1 is a clever way to get it not to do string concatenation :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is maybe a bit more readable form on the original approved answer.

```
const getSeconds = (hms: string) : number => {
  const [hours, minutes, seconds] = hms.split(':');
  return (+hours) * 60 * 60 + (+minutes) * 60 + (+seconds);
};
```

Comment: You should mention that this is *TYPESCRIPT*, and __WON'T WORK__ if you copy and paste this as VANILLA JAVASCRIPT.

Answer (score 5):

Javascript's static method `Date.UTC()` does the trick:

```
alert(getSeconds('00:22:17'));

function getSeconds(time)
{
    var ts = time.split(':');
    return Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, ts[0], ts[1], ts[2]) / 1000;
}
```

Comment: Nice trick with `Date.UTC()`, though note that this does assume that there are always two colons in the string, so parsing `"12:42"` wouldn't work without additional handling.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Date(moment('23:04:33', "HH:mm")).getTime()
```

**Output:** 1499755980000 (in millisecond) 
            ( 1499755980000/1000) (in second)

Note : this output calculate diff from 1970-01-01 12:0:0 to now 
       and we need to implement the moment.js

Comment: OP asked for seconds not milliseconds

Comment: Hi  user7294900, Thx for your comment i ll update my answer, jst we need divide by 1000

Answer (score 2):

This is very old question, but here is two liner very easy to understand answer and it works with any of the following format

- hh:mm:ss or h:m:s
- mm:ss or m:s
- ss or s

  ```
  function convertToSecs =(strTime){
      let [s=0, m=0, h=0] = strTime.split(':').reverse();
      return (+h) * 3600 + (+m) * 60 + (+s); 
  };
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This function works for MM:SS as well:

```js
const convertTime = (hms) => {
        if (hms.length <3){
         return hms
        } else if (hms.length <6){
          const a = hms.split(':')
          return hms = (+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1])
        } else {
          const a = hms.split(':')
          return hms = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2])
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the solution given by Paul https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292588/1191101 but using the old function notation so it can also be used in other js engines (e.g.  java Rhino)

```
function strToSeconds (stime)
{
   return +(stime.split(':').reduce(function (acc,time) { return +(60 * acc) + +time }));
}
```

or just this one more readable

```
function strToSeconds (stime)
{
  var tt = stime.split(':').reverse ();
  return ((tt.length >= 3) ? (+tt[2]): 0)*60*60 + 
         ((tt.length >= 2) ? (+tt[1]): 0)*60 + 
         ((tt.length >= 1) ? (+tt[0]): 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slightly different approach to most other answers here:

```js
// Solution:
const hmsToSeconds = s => /^\d+:\d+:\d+$/.test(s) ? s.split(':').reduce((x, y) => x * 60 | y) : NaN;


// Test cases to check correctness:
`0:0:0
0:0:1
0:1:0
1:0:0
1:1:1
1:1
1
:1:1
1:1:f
foo`
.split('\n')
.forEach(s => console.log(`${s} = ${hmsToSeconds(s)}`));
```

This isn't *just* because it's fun to write your own little one-liner; I believe this is *probably* a safer option than the other answers most of the time.

There is a dangerous flaw in the logic behind the several answers saying e.g. 'this code will also handle mm:ss and ss!', in that it confidently assumes that when it consumes, say, `'13:37'` that it should be reading '13 minutes & 37 seconds', rather than '23 minutes to 2'.

The opposite assumption would probably be the safer bet, I would personally have though. But ultimately it is best to not make *any* assumptions without actual solid basis in the *actual* sources of data the specific system is going to encounter. The last thing you want is a bad assumption like this in a tiny snippet of code buried deep in your codebase to go off like a landmine when months down the line data from a slightly different source starts failing silently.

This solution should pretty confidently reject anything not in the *exact* form `'<int>:<int>:<int>'` and just evaluate to `NaN`. This is likely to be noticed much sooner than the system (potentially intermittently!) be off in some calculations by a factor of 60.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function parsehhmmsst(arg) {
 var result = 0, arr = arg.split(':')
 if (arr[0] < 12) {
  result = arr[0] * 3600 // hours
 }
 result += arr[1] * 60 // minutes
 result += parseInt(arr[2]) // seconds
 if (arg.indexOf('P') > -1) {  // 8:00 PM > 8:00 AM
  result += 43200
 }
 return result
}
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('12:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('1:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('2:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('3:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('4:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('5:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('6:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('7:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('8:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('9:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('10:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('11:00:00 AM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('12:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('1:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('2:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('3:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('4:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('5:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('6:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('7:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('8:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('9:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('10:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
$('body').append(parsehhmmsst('11:00:00 PM') + '<br>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this dynamically - in case you encounter not only: HH:mm:ss, but also, mm:ss, or even ss alone.

```
var str = '12:99:07';
var times = str.split(":");
times.reverse();
var x = times.length, y = 0, z;
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    z = times[i] * Math.pow(60, i);
    y += z;
}
console.log(y);
```