# How to convert time e.g. 00:31:26 into a number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to compare the run times of marathon runners, im having difficulty comparing the run times as they are in the following format; 00:31:26, 00:34:29 (Hours:Minutes:Seconds).

Ideally I would like to convert the whole time into minutes so that I could then use the times to create a graph.

How could I convert the race times into a number using javascript or otherwise?

Comment: As seconds is the smallest part that you are displaying, would it not be sensible to convert to seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example demonstrates [Array.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string into components, hours, minutes and seconds which are held in the variable [`array`](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array&ei=jYiHUdX1JMb-4QS9w4HYCA&usg=AFQjCNFNQx8ugeJT4KMgckvHlM-GffTQqg&sig2=Lf0ht24DiO8qDkmSF5DWvw&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bGE). It then uses [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the component strings into an integer, which are then in turn mathematically multiplied and added together to give you a representation in seconds.

```
var time = "01:32:29";
var array = time.split(":");
var seconds = (parseInt(array[0], 10) * 60 * 60) + (parseInt(array[1], 10) * 60) + parseInt(array[2], 10)

console.log(seconds);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/6aMTj/)

Answer (score 3):

Same basic method, more succinctly

```
  '02:04:03'.split (':').reduce (function (seconds, v) {
      return +v + seconds * 60;
    }, 0) / 60;
```

The split creates an array, the reduce and its function calculates the time in seconds, which is finally divided by 60 to get minutes as a floating point number. The result of the above is 124.05.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert into seconds as you have your time in hh:mm:ss. If you convert direct to minutes, you may not get exact time. You need to implement it this way :

**Example** :

```
var hms = '03:09:56';    // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

// minutes are worth 60 seconds. Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 

//if you want hours
var minutes = (seconds)/60;

console.log(minutes);
```

Comment: It's ok to copy code from [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9640384/502381), but if you do so you should credit the original author.

Answer (score 0):

Without a library, I would use something like this

```
convertToMinutes = function(timeString) {
    var hms = timeString.split(':');
    return Math.ceil(parseInt(hms[2])/60) + parseInt(hms[1]) + parseInt(hms[0])*60
}
```

demo

http://jsbin.com/awiyir/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use the built in Date object. Then you can use built in functions for calculations, formatting etc.

Since Date is a date and not a simple time, I suggest aligning it with unix time. Then .getTime() will get the correct number of milliseconds.

```
var time1 = new Date ('01 01 70 00:31:26 UTC');
var time2 = new Date ('01 01 70 00:29:15 UTC');
var timediff=time1-time2;  // Gets the time diff in millisecs
```

It is a bit hackish, but it works well.

More about the Date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date