# Parsing time-strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have this web server that parses an XML-file with a certain 'time-period'.

The time-period is presented as follows (I can't change this):

`00:05:00`
`00:09:15`
`01:13:15` in an `HH:MM:SS` format.

I want to do an `_.filter()` select on all objects with a date between for instance `00:00:00` and `00:10:00`, and then a filter with all objects between `00:10:00` and `00:20:00`.

EDIT (clarification): With the time periods are 'times watched'. Let's say there are 50 entries of the time period, ranging from 00:00:00 to 1:30:00, but I want to make a new list that contains

- The time period
- The average 'times watched' in that time period.

This means I need some way to say: 'Select all time periods between zero minutes and 10 minutes. Give me a list of those. Compute the mean'.

For that, I would need to have some possibility to do arithmetic operations, seeing I would like to

- Compare dates
- Add 10 minutes on each iteration

However, the Javascript `Date` object doesn't seem to handle 'just times' that well, neither does the `moment.js` library. How would I go for this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean in your 4th paragraph (filter)?  I'm taking that you want to run `_.filter()` twice, once checking for `00:00:00` to `00:10:00`, and the second `00:10:00` to `00:20:00`.  Also, about "Add 10 minutes on each iteration", is that for all of them in the filter, or selected ones within the filter?

Comment: I added some clarification!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HH:MM:SS string to seconds only in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do in JS:

```
times=['00:05:00', '00:09:15', '01:13:15'];
```

1. First get seconds

   ```
   function getsec(time){
     arr=time.split(':');
     return (+arr[0])*3600 + (+arr[1])*60 + (+arr[2]);
   }

   times.map(getsec)
   [ 300, 555, 4395 ]
   ```
2. Then filter times into slots of particular time period

   ```
   function filter(last, curr, index, array){
     chk=parseInt(curr/600); //slots for 10 minutes
     if (typeof last[chk] === 'undefined')
     {
       last[chk]=[];
       last[chk].push(curr);
     }
     else
       last[chk].push(curr);
     return(last)
   }

   times.map(getsec).reduce(filter,[]);
   [ [ 300, 555 ], , , , , , , [ 4395 ] ]
   ```

   Returns array of arrays. Each child array contains times within slots in increasing order
3. Calculate mean

   ```
   function avg(last, curr, index, array){
     if(index==array.length-1)
     return (last+curr)/array.length;
     else
     return last+curr;
   }

   times.map(getsec).reduce(avg,0);
   1750

   function getavg(arr){
     return arr.reduce(avg,0);
   }

   times.map(getsec).reduce(filter,[]).map(getavg);
   [ 427.5, , , , , , , 4395 ]
   ```

   Since we are dealing with array of arrays we need a wrapper.

Finally I would say that if you have many entries, databases would be faster.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way would be for you to convert everything into seconds, and then do your thing.

```
inSeconds = function(time) {
  var secs, arr = [];
  arr = time.split(':').map(function(item) { return parseInt(item) });
  secs = arr[0]*3600 + arr[1]*60 + arr[2];
  return secs;
}
```

Comment: Oh my bad, I hadn't converted the string to int.