# plus signs in the JS code - why aren't they optional here

Tags: javascript, string, function, time

I'm curious about the answer that was taken by Dagg Nabbit at 
[SO here: Convert HH:MM:SS string to seconds only in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript)

```
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
```

Right,

```
var seconds = (a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (a[1]) * 60 + (a[2]);
```

doesnt work as expected - it doesn't calculate the number of seconds.
Why?

Comment: Just a side-note: not all plus-operators are required: `a[0] * 60 * 60 + a[1] * 60 + (+a[2]);` will work just fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They cause an implicit conversion of a string into a number. In your browser's debug console, try:

```
> typeof +'1'
"number"
> typeof '1'
"string"
```