# Convert HH:MM:SS into minute using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, time

How can I Convert HH:MM:SS into minute using javascript ?

Comment: what you mean with minute? post input-output example please

Comment: split the string on `:` parseInt and do appropriate multiplications/divisions on each of the 3 parts in the result

Comment: could you post you code?

Answer (score 35):

Use split and multiply per 60 ignoring seconds.

Taking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript) as base:

```
var hms = '02:04:33';   // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

// Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var minutes = (+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1]);

console.log(minutes);
```

Use split and multiply per 60 using seconds as decimal (thus is not full exact)

```
var hms = '02:04:33';   // your input string
var a = hms.split(':'); // split it at the colons

// Hours are worth 60 minutes.
var minutes = (+a[0]) * 60 + (+a[1]);

console.log(minutes + "," + ((+a[2]) / 60));
```

Answer (score -8):

To know time functions & formats in JS you must read the [manual](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp).

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getMinutes());
```

Comment: this does not create a valid date object

Comment: Correct. Thanks for the heads up.