# JavaScript calculated field

Tags: javascript

I just can't see what am I doing wrong... It doesn't calculate the "stunden" field.

There is some small mistake from my side and I just can't see it.

EDITED: now all is working as it should

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.item').keyup(function(){

    var starts = 0;
    var ends = 0;
    var stunden = 0;

    if (!isNaN($(this).find(".starts").val())) {
      starts = $(this).find(".starts").val();
    }
    if (!isNaN($(this).find(".ends").val())) {
      ends = $(this).find(".ends").val();
    }

    stunden = ends - starts;
    $(this).find(".stunden").val(stunden);

  });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="t1" class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Start Time</th>
      <th class="text-center">End Time</th>
      <th class="text-center">Stunden</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1" class="item">
      <td><input name="starts[]" class="starts form-control" ></td>
      <td><input name="ends[]" class="ends form-control" ></td>
      <td><input name="stunden[]" class="stunden form-control" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2" class="item">
      <td><input name="starts[]" class="starts form-control" ></td>
      <td><input name="ends[]" class="ends form-control" ></td>
      <td><input name="stunden[]" class="stunden form-control" readonly="readonly" ></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What this code is suppose to do? What is expected output?

Comment: just to calculate the stunden input field from the starts and ends fields. stunden field is readonly and is a difference between starts and ends.

Comment: `.stunden` is readonly and you listen to a keyup event on this input control. Therefore it's not possible this code will ever get executed

Comment: yes you are right :( i changed it to listen .ends on keyup and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are recalculating when a key is pressed in the `.stunden` fields, so you should move the event to the other inputs, or the parent row. You'll need something like this.

```
$('.item').keyup(function(){
  var starts = 0;
  var ends = 0;
  var stunden = 0;
  if (!isNaN($(this).find(".starts").val())) {
    starts = $(this).find(".starts").val();
  }
  if (!isNaN($(this).find(".ends").val())) {
    ends = $(this).find(".ends").val();
  }
  stunden = starts - ends;
  $(this).find(".stunden").val(stunden);
});
```

Comment: @lewis4u You might want to try to search for an answer for a change. The chances that you are the first person in the world to have this problem are exactly **zero**. Also, don't post follow-up questions in the comments on StackOverflow.

Comment: @lewis4u, I agree with Tomalak, but just to help you out a bit, take a look at this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Let me try your original keyup code `.ends` ,I just want to explain how is work below code

- call `.starts` ,we currently in `tr>td>input` ,so need backup to `tr` by `parent()` then we find `.starts` inside its elements.As also `.ends`
- find `.studen` is also in state `tr>td>input` ,so backup to `td` and go next `td` by next() then find `.studen` .

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.ends').keyup(function(){
              var starts = 0;
              var ends = 0;
              var stunden = 0;            
              if (!isNaN($(this).parent().parent().find(".starts").val())) {
                  starts = $(this).parent().parent().find(".starts").val();
              }
              if (!isNaN($(this).parent().parent().find(".ends").val())) {
                  ends = $(this).parent().parent().find(".ends").val();
              }            
              stunden = starts - ends;
              $(this).parent().next().find('.stunden').val(stunden);

      });    
  });
  ```

Comment: it doesn't work with $('.ends').keyup(function(){ ----- but with $('.item').keyup(function(){ it works

Comment: Yes now I tested it, it works....but for me it was much simpler to change only one word ".item" instead of ".ends"

Comment: yes I know it ! Just inform you ,your original code can also worked !