# get time from textfield and convert to seconds

Tags: php, jquery

How can I get the time entered into an input field and pass it to jQuery to show in a `div` in seconds? I would like to use the jQuery `show()` function if possible. Would this keep it triggered if browser is refreshed?

To convert the time I'm using this but I'm getting 0 seconds.

```
function TimeToSec() {
    $sec = 0;
    foreach (array(explode(':', $input_time)) as $k => $v) 
        $sec += pow(60, $k) * $v;

    return $sec;
```

and I'm triggering using jQuery:

```
function live() {
    jQuery(".live").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the seconds of the time entered you can use the same solution detailed in this other question:
[Convert HH:MM:SS string to seconds only in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript)