# Adding HH:MM:SS strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, time, addition

I don't think I can figure this out on my own. 
Lets say I have a time in the string format of HH:MM:SS ex. `10:11:06` and I would like to add another time to it and return it as a string. ex. `"10:11:06" + "11:00:01" would return "21:11:07"`

I have gone through this site coming up with a solution of converting it to seconds and then adding them together as such:

```
function addTimes(start, end) {
 var a = start.split(":");
 var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 
 var b = end.split(":");
 var seconds2 = (+b[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]); 

 var date = new Date(1970,0,1);
     date.setSeconds(seconds + seconds2);

 var c = date.toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
     return c;
     console.log(c);
}
```

Yet console.log C returns an Invalid Date. Is this still a string or am I doing something wrong?

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9640384/3317267) [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17781037/3317267)

EDIT: (I was stupid) I had this in a recursive loop and I initialized the sum variable with a `var s = 0;` instead of a `var s = "00:00:00";`

Comment: Why on Earth are you going through all of this? `new Date(1970,0,1,+a[0],+a[1],+a[2]);`

Comment: In the code snipped that you've posted, `console.log(c);` will never be executed because you `return` from the function before that call. I've just tested this function and it works for the example start and end time (`10:11:06` and `11:00:01`) that you've provided but it will definitely fail if the `start` and `end` time add up to more then `24` hours.

Comment: @Titus I do have a console.log on the outside checking the function. Thank you, I just realized it might be my other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
var start = "10:11:06";
var end = "10:11:06";
  var a = start.split(":");
 var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]); 
 var b = end.split(":");
 var seconds2 = (+b[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]); 

 var date = new Date(1970,0,1);
     date.setSeconds(seconds + seconds2);

 var c = date.toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
var c = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
return c;
```

to convert date object to time.