# How can I convert '00: 30: 00 ' format to seconds?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to convert the format example '00: 30: 00' on seconds. This is my way. Is there a way to add these values in the 'template string'?

expected effect:

convert1000('00:30:00') --> 1800

convert1000('00:00:10') --> 10

convert1000('00:08:10') --> 490

convert1000('01:01:10') --> 3670

```
const convert1000 = (time) => {
    const [hour, minute, sec] = time.split(':');

    if (hour !== "00") {
      return `${(hour* 3600)} + ${(minute * 60)} + ${(sec)}`;
    }

    if (minute !== "00") {
      return `${minute * 60} + ${sec} `;
    }

    return `${sec} `;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want a template string here? Seems rather odd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HH:MM:SS string to seconds only in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript)

Comment: Use only one ${} but still seems odd.

Comment: Like this maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rbzhtep9/

Comment: You want a `sscanf` from good old C? Alas, I don't believe vanilla JS has it.

Comment: This question is really not about how to convert it, OP is doing it.... lol, question is about how to use string templates literals to do a calculation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `asSeconds` from [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/) duration objects

```
moment.duration('00:30:00').asSeconds();
```

Comment: Don't know why I get a down vote, as the question is flagged momentjs...

Comment: My bad, my original answer did not work actually. Updated it.

Answer (score 5):

You could split and reduce the values by multiplying the former value by `60` and then add the value.

```js
const convert1000 = time => time.split(':').reduce((s, t) => s * 60 + +t, 0);
  
console.log(convert1000('00:30:00')); // 1800
console.log(convert1000('00:00:10')); // 10
console.log(convert1000('00:08:10')); // 58 is wrong, because 8 minutes is 480 plus 10 sec
console.log(convert1000('01:01:10')); // 3670
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it like this

```
const convert1000 = (time) => {
  const [h,m,s] = time.split(':');
  let seconds = (h*3600) + (m * 60) + parseInt(s);
  return seconds;
}

alert(convert1000("00: 30: 00"))
```

See the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/q4zvsowe/

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the string numbers into integers first.
This should work the way you intend:

```
let convert1000 = (timeString) => {
    let [hour, minute, second] = timeString.split(':').map(Number);
    return `${(hour* 3600) + (minute * 60) + (second)}`;
}
```

Note that this returns a string; if you want it to be a number, just remove the templating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `+` inside the braces to make them sum numbers.

You should put it inside one `${}`

So your code would be like below:

```
const convert2000 = (time) => {
    const [hour, minute, sec] = time.split(':');

    if (hour !== "00") {
      return `${hour* 3600 + minute * 60 + sec}`;
    }

    if (minute !== "00") {
      return `${minute * 60 + sec} `;
    }

    return `${sec}`;
}
```

Comment: issue is sec is a string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const convert1000 = (time) => {
  const [hour, minute, sec] = time.split(':');
  return hour * 3600 + minute * 60 + sec * 1;
};

console.log(convert1000('00:30:00'));
```