# Get the difference between two variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an object and Hours is saved as a string . I need to convert the string to hours and then get the difference between the 2 variables.

```
const groupSchedule=[
    {"days":"sat","Hourfrom":"15:00","Hourto":"19:00"},
    {"days":"sun","Hourfrom":"15:00","Hourto":"19:00"},
    {"days":"mon","Hourfrom":"15:00","Hourto":"19:00"},
]
function numberOfHoursInWeek(groupSchedule) {
    let hours = 0;
    for (const gSchedule of groupSchedule) {
           let hour = gSchedule.Hourto.to - gSchedule.Hourfrom;
        console.log(hour);
        hours += hour;
    }
    return hours;
}
```

Problem in converting string to hour (NAN)

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there's no such property as `to` on Hoursto in `gSchedule.Hourto.to`

Comment: If you don't want to struggle with Date.parse without an actual date, you could consider using Moment.js. That library has better ways for parsing time strings like 'Moment("15:00", "HH:mm")'. And you can also easily run calculations on moments.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write in a very verbose way. You could do something like this:

```
const hoursTo = "19:33";
const hoursFrom = "14:55";
const hoursToArray = hoursTo.split(":");
const hoursFromArray = hoursFrom.split(":");
const hoursToDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, hoursToArray[0], hoursToArray[1], 0, 0); 
const hoursFromDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, hoursFromArray[0], hoursFromArray[1], 0, 0); 
const difference = Math.abs(hoursToDate - hoursFromDate) / 36e5;
console.log(hours) //4.633333333333334;
```

Answer (score -1):

The basic issue is that you are taking `gSchedule.hourTo` and `gSchedule.hourFrom` and trying to perform arithmetic with them when they are string values. You need to split the string and extract a numeric type to perform this type of mathematical calculation.

In this case the relevant numeric portion is the hours portion of the `HH:MM`string, so using the split function with `:` as a delimiter will return a list of two string, one string of hours and one of minutes. We can then parse the hours string to get an int, float, or other numeric type.

```
//split time strings on the ':'
let hrToSplit = gSchedule.hourTo.split(':')
let hrFromSplit = gSchedule.hourFrom.split(':')

//parse time strings to extract hour as int
let hrToNum = parseInt(hrToSplit[0], 10)
let hrFromNum = parseInt(hrFromSplit[0], 10)

//perform whatever math is needing using the numbers themselves, not the strings
console.log(hrToNum + hrFromNum)
```

If you want to do some further reading on different approaches beyond the answers you got here, [this is a similar question that may be useful to reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript)

Comment: Why not just parse it as a `Date` and allow the objects do the time-related math for you?

Comment: I found this to be a simple solution since the question was only concerned with taking `HH:MM` formatted strings and performing math using the hours, but I see how parsing as a `Date` would be a valid approach as well.