# how get value from data object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am facing an issue in React: I have some JSON data and I want to get the `starttime` or `endtime` from it.
How can I do that?

**json data (multiple dates)**

```
data {starttime: "14:30:00", endtime: "15:30:00"}
data {starttime: "15:30:00", endtime: "17:30:00"}
data {starttime: "16:30:00", endtime: "18:30:00"}
data {starttime: "18:30:00", endtime: "19:30:00"}
```

**react component**

```
.map(({ full_name, breaks }) => (
  <span className="more-space" key={full_name}>
    { full_name }<br />
    {
      breaks.filter(data => {
        console.log("start", data.starttime);  //start 14:30:00
        console.log("end", data.endtime);  //end 15:30:00
        const date = new Date(data.starttime);

        const date = new Date(data.starttime);    //date Invalid Date
        const enddate = new Date(data.endtime);   //date Invalid Date
        return date >= prevDate && date < nextDate;
      }
    }
)
```

Comment: What does `data.startTime` and `data.endTime` look like?

Comment: start 14:30:00  end 15:30:00

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert HH:MM:SS string to seconds only in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript)

Comment: It appears as though you got the start and end time values from the object successfully. Do you have a different issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with `const date = new Date(data.starttime);`. Date constructor will not accept the just time format.

Try something like below, create date and then update hours, mins and sec

```js
const starttime = "14:30:00";

const [hours, mins, sec] = starttime.split(':').map(x => Number(x));
const sdate = new Date();
sdate.setHours(hours);
sdate.setMinutes(mins);
sdate.setSeconds(sec);

console.log(sdate.toString());
```