# How to convert string numbers that are written in this format: XX:XX:XX into comparable numbers

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

How would i convert a string like this: 1:13:16 Into a number value? It can go up as high as xx:xx:xx

Hours:minutes:seconds

Example list:
duration: 0:37:29 
duration: 0:25:57 
duration: 1:10:15 
duration: 21:2:55

I need to do some false true comparisons so i need to convert them accurately.

Comment: Take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640266/convert-hhmmss-string-to-seconds-only-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), like so:

```js
let duration = '0:37:29';
let [hours, minutes, seconds] =
  duration.split(':').map(str => Number.parseInt(str));
```