# Comparing two times in MomentJS in the format HH:mm?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Here I need to compare two times and have to check whether the current time is sameOrBefore the given time.

```
  var workingDayTime = '1900'
  var currentTime = moment().format("HH:mm")
  var endTime = moment(workingDayTime,"HHmm").format("HH:mm")

console.log(currentTime) // 08:21
console.log(endTime) // 19:00
```

Assume the value of workingDayTime is coming from API in the format of ``HHMM`. I have checked the moment docs. And used something like `endTime.isSameOrAfter(currentTime)`.

But it is returning `endTime.isSameOrAfter is not a function` . I believe this is because the current time and endTime have formatted to string this is not a function anymore. Is there any way to achieve the functionality I am looking for. Please help me with your suggestion and feedback

Comment: Try convert in milliseconds and compare directly.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9640384/5755317

Comment: Like you said, it because you convert the moment object in a string with format method. Remove all `.format(...)` and your code will work if you use `endTime.isSameOrAfter(currentTime)`

Answer (score 3):

Compare the moment objects without the string formatting:

```
const workingDayTime = '1900'
const currentMoment = moment()
const currentTime = currentMoment.format('HH:mm')
const endMoment = moment(workingDayTime,"HHmm")
const endTime = endMoment.format("HH:mm")

const msg = (endMoment.isSameOrAfter(currentMoment))
  ? 'after'
  : 'before'
console.log(`${endTime} is ${msg} ${currentTime}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't format dates before you compare them

```
import moment from "moment";

var workingDayTime = '1900'
var currentTime = moment()
var endTime = moment(workingDayTime,"HHmm")

console.log(endTime.isSameOrAfter(currentTime)) // true
```