# Add minutes to defined time in hour:minute format

Tags: php, time

i got a simple question for some, but not so simple for me.

I want to add a defined amount of minutes to a defined time.
It is a ticket penalty system, and there is a remove function, which are going to be disabled after a certain amount of time.

My code right now is:

```
$clock           = date("H:i", time());
$penaltyTime     = $getInfo["time"];
$allowedTime     = $getInfo["allowed"];
$finalTime       = $penaltyTime + $allowedTime; ???
```

Let us say that penaltyTime is 22:00 and allowedTime is 5, how can i then add the 5 minutes to 22:00, so i have a final variable called $finalTime, where the value is 22:05.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking for [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

Comment: Yeah but that gives me a 10 digit number, and i dont know how to convert it back to H:i format again

Comment: hint: the return value of time() is a rather similar 10 digit number ;-)

Comment: [Convert H:i:s to seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20874702/67332) + add X seconds (minutes * 60) + [convert seconds back to H:i:s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20870843/67332).

Answer (score 0):

Next is the solution to your problem. The time is first converted to a "big number", add the desired time, then converted it back to "normal" time:

```
<?php

$penaltyTime = "22:00";
$allowedTime = 5;

$finalTime = strtotime( $penaltyTime ) + ($allowedTime * 60);
echo gmdate( "H:i:s",$finalTime );

?>
```