# PHP convert mysql query string to mm:ss time format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, formatting

Im trying to get hold of how to get the difference between two mysql varchar strings they are of the format mm:ss where m stands for minutes and s for seconds. So for instance.

```
$a = 13:20;
$b = 13:00;
```

what function do I use so that

```
 $a - $b =  00:20 ?

$a = strtotime('13:20');
$b = strtotime('13:00');
echo "The time difference between 13:20 and 13:00 is : "  . ($a - $b);

Gives me 
The time difference between 13:20 and 13:00 is : 1200

Kindly take note of my original format. mm:ss
```

Comment: What you are providing is in hour format....

Comment: I guess  so but unfortunately thats how its found in the database. How do I work around this. Thanks

Comment: Show me how it's stored in your database..

Comment: I have a column entries like 18:30 , 66:15,  17:40, 16:59, 90:48 etc etc all in the form of mm:ss . Thanks

Comment: [Convert `min:sec` format to seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-hhmmss-to-seconds-only/20874702#20874702), subtract seconds, and then [convert seconds back to `min:sec` format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond/20870843#20870843).

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()`

Try this...

```
$time1 = explode(':', '13:20');
$time2 = explode(':', '13:00');

$a = 00 . ':' . $time1[0] . ':' . $time1[1];
$b = 00 . ':' . $time2[0] . ':' . $time2[1];

echo "The time difference between 13:20 and 13:00 is : "  . (strtotime($a) - strtotime($b));
```

Comment: $a = strtotime('13:20');
$b = strtotime('13:00');
echo "The time difference between 13:20 and 13:00 is : "  . ($a - $b);

Gives me 
The time difference between 13:20 and 13:00 is : 1200

Kindly take note of my original format. mm:ss

Comment: `00:13:20` and `00:13:00` because if you use `13:20` and `13:00` it reads as `13:20:00` and `13:00:00` it returns 1200...

Comment: It works , now how do I use that in a mysql to query a Database ? Thanks

Comment: change `explode(':', '13:20')` with `explode(':', $row['time'])`

Comment: "It works , now how do I use that in a mysql to query a Database"

Comment: You can do this in an SQL query thus: SELECT TIME(REPLACE(`col`, ':', '')). What this does is to strip the colon(:) out of the varchar value so that TIME() will parse it as minutes and seconds. You can then use the native date functions in your query to calculate the diference between 2 times. SELECT TIMEDIFF(TIME(REPLACE(`time1`)), TIME(REPLACE(`time1`))). That will give you the difference between the 2 times. I believe that was the question you were asking. I would add an answer except that this has been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: And that is a typo, should be SELECT TIMEDIFF(TIME(REPLACE('13:20',':','')), TIME(REPLACE('13:00',':',''))). Of course you would substitute the actual columns for the string literals in my example.

Comment: Will also give that a try. Thanks will let you know how it goes.