# How to turn HH:MM:SS:MS into just seconds?

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently grabbing the length of a mp3 file from ffmpeg which results in a time such as 00:03:50.76 I'm needing to turn this into just total seconds without the milliseconds.

So the above would be 230 seconds. Would regex suffice for this?

Comment: Almost, was having issues with the milliseconds however

Comment: This question, while old, is not actually a duplicate -- the linked SO post and solution do not cover handling time with milliseconds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-time-in-hhmmss-format-to-seconds-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$res = "00:04:12.44";
$ex = explode(".", $res);
$res = $ex[0];
$secs = strtotime("01.01.1970 " . $res);
```

---

Or - see the comment of Sven:

```
$res = "00:03:50.76";
$ex = explode(".", $res);
$res = $ex[0];
$ex = explode(":", $res);
$secs = $ex[0] * 3600 + $ex[1] * 60 + $ex[2]; // 230 secs
```

Comment: This works, however it appears to be rounding the seconds to the nearest minute. Here is what I'm getting, seconds are on the left and the HH:MM:SS:MS I have are on the right https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4331988/ShareX/2015/07/2015-07-18_17-18-39.txt

Comment: Nevermind, $ex[0] should have been $ex[2]. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry :D I changed it - this solution is even easier.

Comment: This is a dangerous solution because the return value of `strtotime()` depends on the currently set timezone. Not setting this to UTC will produce wrong results. It will also not work for times of 25 hours or more.

Comment: @Sven: Thank you! I will add the other solution, too