# add hours:min:sec to date in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, addition

I am trying to add hh:mm:ss with the date. How can i do it?

I tried with the following but it works when the hour is string, but when adding time is similar to MySQL Date time it is not working.

```
$new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 hours'));
```

I am trying to get solution for the following:

```
$timeA= '2015-10-09 13:40:14'; 

$timeB = '03:05:01';  // '0000-00-00 03:05:01'
```

**OutPut:**

```
$timeA + $timeB = 2015-10-09 16:45:15 ?
```

How Can I Add this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php):

```
$timeA = new DateTime('2015-10-09 13:40:14');
$timeB = new DateInterval('PT3H5M1S'); // '03:05:01'; 
$timeA->add($timeB);
echo $timeA->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You would need to break your time down into the right DateInterval format but that is easily done with `explode()`;

Here's how that  might look:

```
$parts = array_map(function($num) {
    return (int) $num;
}, explode(':', '03:05:01'));

$timeA = new DateTime('2015-10-09 13:40:14');
$timeB = new DateInterval(sprintf('PT%uH%uM%uS', $parts[0], $parts[1], $parts[2]));
$timeA->add($timeB);
echo $timeA->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/447730)

Comment: in my DB the value will be '03:05:01' in this format show i convert for all?

Comment: You can break up your datetime format into smaller parts and build a date dynamically. But that's even more work than this.

Comment: then what if i need to add a second date in this formate ''2015-10-09 13:40:14' @john

Comment: Um, you do the same thing

Answer (score 3):

```
 print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($timeA." +03 hour +05 minutes +01 seconds"));
```

Should work also.

So:

```
$timeA= '2015-10-09 13:40:14'; 

$timeB = vsprintf(" +%d hours +%d minutes +%d seconds", explode(':', '03:05:01')); 

print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($timeA.$timeB));
```

Can be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may also convert the time into seconds with this approach from: [Convert time in HH:MM:SS format to seconds only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-hhmmss-to-seconds-only)

```
$time = '03:05:01';
$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
```

Then you could add the seconds to

```
$currentTime = '2015-10-10 13:40:14';
$newTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $currentTime.'+'.$seconds.' seconds'));
```

If you prefer to use the DateTime objects offered by @John Conde, here are two ways to convert the time string into the format:

```
$formattedTime = preg_replace("/(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/","PT$1H$2M$3S","03:05:11");
```

or, as you read it from the database:

```
select concat(hour(last_modified),'H',minute(last_modified),'M',second(last_modified),'H') from people;
```

So a more general code approach would be:

```
$initial = 'some time';
$interval = 'the interval value';

$initialTime = new DateTime($initial);
$intervalTime = new DateInterval($interval);
$initialTime->add($intervalTime);
echo $initialTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```