# PHP get the sum of hours of the two arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, time, sum

I have an array like following and inside it 2 arrays that have a value and want to know how to get the sum of both hours for example 01:00 + 04:00 = 05:00

## Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total_time] => 01:00
        }
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total_time] => 04:00
        }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: how do you declare your array , can i have the code to debug it easier for you?

Comment: What happens if the sum of hours exceed 24?

Answer (score 0):

There would be a lot of different ways to achieve this. I prefer to use array_map to get the values out of the object and convert the values. The it should be easy enough for array_sum to sum it all together.

```
$hours_array = array_map("get_hours", $array);
$results = array_sum($hours_array);

function get_hours($object) {
    // Check values first

    // For just hours.
    list($hours,) = explode(":", $object->{'total_time'});

    return $hours;
}
```

Comment: What about minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

- loop over array;
- convert `HH:MM` format to seconds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874702/67332);
- sum all converted seconds;
- convert summed seconds back to `HH:MM` format like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond/20870843#20870843).