# Inserting a percentage of a TIME type value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a MySQL that needs to insert a TIME type value into a table.

Currently it goes

```
INSERT INTO my_table (time_value) VALUES ('05:00:00')
```

What can I put around the '05:00:00' that it will be a specified % of that value (eg if it were 20% it would be inserted at '01:00:00')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [time_to_sec()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) function to get the time in seconds, perform the calculation, then convert the seconds back to time using [sec_to_time()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) function:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (time_value) VALUES (sec_to_time(time_to_sec('05:00:00') * 0.2))
```

Or just do the same calculation in php and just insert the result into MySQL. See [Convert time in HH:MM:SS format to seconds only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-time-in-hhmmss-format-to-seconds-only) question here on SO for time to second conversion.

Comment: beat me to it. Kept this open in another tab and was doing something else

Comment: happens to all of us :)