# php - Converting Time From HH:MM:SS Format That Has A Dot To Seconds

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I have this kind of string:

`$duration = "00:20:55.60000";`

It was extracted from a video using `ffmpeg`. I need to convert it to seconds.

I had tried this: `strtotime("1970-01-01 $duration UTC");` (I get it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874702/2232458)) but it's not working. May be because it is containing dot at the seconds part.

Is there a way to convert that string to seconds?

Comment: Why not just explode it on ':', multiply the first and second elements and then sum the values

Comment: Do `strtotime("1970-01-01 ".substr($duration,0,8)." UTC");` that will fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
$duration = "00:20:55.60000";
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($duration));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$duration = "00:20:55.60000";
echo time(strtotime($duration));
// returns : 1485346959
```

Or

```
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($duration));
// returns: 00:20:55
```

[Working Code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/867a343efc567250198cc156fd894c125c7f1056)

Answer (score 0):

just use DateTime class.

```
$now = '00:20:55.60000';
$timevalue = new DateTime($now);
$onlytime = $timevalue->format('H:i:s');
echo $onlytime ;
```