# {Carbon} Convert time in HH:MM:SS format into seconds in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to convert the time which I got from `$scheduleTime = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($scheduleTimestamp)->toTimeString();` which is currently giving me `07:32:40` now I want to convert it into seconds only using Carbon library is this possible to do so if yes then how?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to get unix timestamp format? If that's the case just append `->timestamp` like `Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($scheduleTimestamp)->timestamp;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert time in HH:MM:SS format to seconds only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-time-in-hhmmss-format-to-seconds-only)

Comment: Change `->toTimeString()` to `->format('s')`

Comment: @hopesfall he wants it in Carbon format used by laravel

Comment: nope I want whole time in seconds is it possible in carbon with getting involved into regular expression mess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, its there in carbon itself just use `secondsSinceMidnight()` and you are good to go.

```
 $scheduleTimeSeconds = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($scheduleTimestamp)->secondsSinceMidnight();
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use

```
$scheduleTime =\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($scheduleTimestamp)->diffInMinutes()
```

to display the time in minute or

```
$scheduleTime =\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($scheduleTimestamp)->diffInSeconds()
```

to display it in second

Answer (score 3):

```
private function convertTimeToSecond(string $time): int
{
    $d = explode(':', $time);
    return ($d[0] * 3600) + ($d[1] * 60) + $d[2];
}
```

Example, after 2 year...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this 
it will return only the seconds

`$scheduleTime =\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($scheduleTimestamp)->second;`
 or

`$scheduleTime =\Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($scheduleTimestamp)-> diffInSeconds();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$scheduleTime = Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC($scheduleTimestamp)->toTimeString();

$sec = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $scheduleTime);

sscanf($sec, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);

$time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
```

Comment: looks like I need to go for that core thing nothing in carbon for me?

Comment: @BhavikBamania I'm sorry I don't have any idea on how to do it using Carbon library

Comment: it's fine I got the answer check my answer :)