# How to convert HOURS:MINUTES to seconds in PHP?

Tags: php

How to convert hour:minutes to seconds in php? I want to convert this value example: 6:30 (6 hours 30 minutes).

```
    echo gmdate("H:i", 11685); // this is to convert seconds to hours:minutes
```

I need reverse for this..

Comment: Very similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-time-in-hhmmss-format-to-seconds-only

Comment: have you tried anything before asking for an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Just split it up and do the math, not hard.

```
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time, 2);
$seconds = $minutes * 60 + $hours * 3600;
```

Comment: No one said it is **hard**.