# Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have this php code

```
$DayJobTime = ($JobEnd - $JobStart - $Break) * 60;
echo "$DayJobTime";
```

and i get the correct answer - 480 minutes, but for me show Notices 
"Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in " 3 times

JobEnd, JobStart and Break i get from datebase and it looks like this

```
JobEnd -   08:00:00
JobStart - 17:00:00
Break -    01:00:00
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Arithmetic operators can only be done on numbers. `08:00:00` is not a number.

Comment: PHP just parses the beginning, `17:00:00` is treated as just `17`, but you get the warning because of the extra.

Comment: how can I calculate differently?

Comment: Convert your time strings to integer numbers of seconds, then perform the calculation using those numbers. Read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-time-in-hhmmss-format-to-seconds-only

Comment: Use `explode(':', $JobEnd)` to convert it to an array, then the minutes is `60 * $array[0] + $array[1]`.