# How to output sql date row to time elapsed

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have table with row id, name, created_at and I want to output the created_at row as timestamp time ago in php

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

replace `time()` method with `created_at`

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

Is this will help you ?
[Convert time in HH:MM:SS format to seconds only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834202/convert-time-in-hhmmss-format-to-seconds-only)

... converted to seconds

```
// example date from db
$created_at = "22-05-15 00:49:59";
$created    = strtotime($created_at);
$current    = strtotime("now");
$diff       = $current - $created;
echo "Diff: " . $diff . " \n";
```

Comment: It display date and time but I want it to display in time elapsed like 1 hours ago, 1 day ago, 1 year ago etc

Comment: ok .. so the method will be: ``current_time - created_at = 1 Hours ago.``

Comment: What if 2 days?

Comment: yes i know .. so first we need to convert created_at and current time to seconds.. then we do current - created_at = how many seconds..
after that we write a function to convert seconds to minutes & hours & days & months ...

Comment: Can you please write it out

Comment: check updated answer .. and use created_at to be close to seconds ,, 
to check if its working
then we can write method to convert these seconds into string

Comment: It output 187836